# ButterKnife: @BindView but get error saying that button instance variable is not initialized

Tags: android, butterknife

I am using [ButterKnife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) to bind view element.

Here is my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ok_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My fragment:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    @BindView(R.id.ok_btn)
    lateinit var okBtn: Button

    ...

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        okBtn.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Log.d("mytag", "ok clicked!")
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my simple app, I get error:

```
Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property okBtn has not been initialized
E/AndroidRuntime( 5435):    at com.my.app.MyFragment.onViewCreated(MyFragment.kt:35)
```

Why I get this error? It sounds like the `@BindView(R.id.ok_btn)` does't initialize the button instance variable. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is the line like?

```
Butterknife.bind(this, rootView)
```

not sure how it should look on Kotlin
and don't forget to add unbinder
you should use it with fragments according [documentation](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

finally it will look something like...

```
Unbinder unbinder;
onViewCreated(){ 
  unbinder = Butterknife.bind(this, rootView); 
  //here you can set your onClickListener
}
onDestroyView(){
  unbinder.unbind()
}
```

adapt it for Kotlin and bravely use))